Solution verification relating to an exercise on partial orderings.
The following is an exercise from the book "Elements of Set Theory" by Herbert Enderton.

Assume that $<_A$ and $<_B$ are partial orderings on $A$ and $B$ respectively, and that $f$ is a function from $A$ into $B$ such that
$x<_Ay \implies f(x)<_B f(y)$
for any $x$ and $y$ in $A$.
Can we conclude that $f$ is one-to-one?
Can we conclude that
$x<_Ay \iff f(x)<_B f(y)$?

A partial ordering is defined as a relation that is transitive and irreflexive.
My attempt:
We aim to show counter examples for both conjectures.
Let $A=B=P$, the set of positive integers.
Let $<_A = \{(a,b) \in P\times P :(\exists n \in P)( an=b\  \&\  n\neq1)\}$ (a strict "divides" relation), and let $<_B$ be the usual ordering relation on P.
In addition, let $f:P \to P$ such that $f(n)=|\{x\in P:x<_An\}|$ (the number of proper divisors of $n$).
Then for any $x$ and $y$ in $P$, if $x<_Ay$, then $f(x)<_Bf(y)$, since every divisor of $x$ must divide $y$.
Now, note that $f(2)=f(3)$ while $2 \neq 3$ so that $f$ is not one-to-one.
Also, $f(5)<_Bf(4)$ while $5<_A4$ does not hold, contradicting the second conjecture. $\square$
Is my conclusion and justification valid? Could I have used a different method?

Looks good to me.

You could have used some very simple counter-examples, for example $A = {a,b,c}$ with $<_A ={(a,b), (a,c)}$ and $B = {1,2}$ and $f = {(a,1), (b,2), (c,2)}$ to answer the first, and some small variations to answer the second. However, that is just to suggest alternatives, not a problem with anything you did.
